# Does static array vs static const array make difference in terms of memory use?

Tags: c++, c

Does declaring a `static` array (of a primitive type) vs a `static const` array (of a primitive type) make a difference in terms of memory use ?

```
static const int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};
// vs
static int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};
```

Specifically, is a `static const` array 'simply' the executable's data that is loaded in memory vs a copy of that array in case of only `static` ?  The latter then means the data is in memory twice and needs to be copied during startup.

I'm thinking specifically about an array global to a unit (declared in the cpp file).
Is there any difference with declaring inside a function instead, in terms of memory ?
Is (IF a copy is made) the copy made when the function is called first ?  And so, what if the function is never called ?

PS. I currently use C++ Builder 11.3 using Clang

Comment: I can't speak for every possible implementation, but in the ones I know about, nothing is copied based on this alone.

Comment: This will depend entirely on how the compiler chooses to generate code for these statements. It may possibly even depend on particular options. There's no general answer.

Comment: Your question is comparing `static const` vs `static`, but your code shows `static const` vs `const`.  So which is it?

Comment: It depends. For example, on some embedded platforms the initial values of the non-const, non-zero, statically allocated objects need to be copied from ROM to RAM during program startup, so they will be be using up some space in both ROM and RAM.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without specifying a specific compiler toolchain.

Comment: Regarding the other part of the question, if the optimizer cannot eliminate the function's static variables then it needs to allocate space for them. The same is true for static (internal linkage) variables at the file level. If the compiler cannot eliminate them then it needs to allocate space for them.

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for `constexpr int data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};`

Comment: Assuming you are asking about `const` vs `static const`, you can't return pointer to elements of array in former case.

Comment: Note that you can't name your array `int` as that is a keyword and can't be used as an identifier.

Comment: @dbush  Oops, fixed, I mean `static`

Comment: It will depend on the implementation.   Considerations will include both physical memory (e.g. ROM, RAM, possibly [I don't know] even cache) and logical memory (e.g. virtual versus non-virtual) architecture of the host machine, capabilities supported by executable file formats, design choices in the toolchain (e.g. compiler optimisation, linker optimisation, if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, please note that this depends on a whole lot of things - the type of system and the compiler used, what level of optimizations that are enabled, how the "C runtime" works for the given system and so on.

---

Contrary to a common misconception, data can't be stored in "thin air" - it always has to go somewhere. What the compiler can do is to optimize away the array allocation and place the array contents inside the machine code. The data sections shrinks but the executable section increases - the total amount of memory allocated ought to be around the same.

The reason for such optimizations is typically speed optimizations - you can shave down the total amount of instructions if you don't have to load the values from RAM into a register.

For example

```c
#include <stdio.h>
static const int array[4] = {1,2,3,4};

void func (void)
{
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
      printf("%d%",array[i]);
}
```

On gcc -O3 for x86_64, this boiled down to a bunch of `movl $1, %esi`, `movl $2, %esi` etc instructions. The numbers are still there but part of the `movl` instructions in the executable code instead.

Some things of note:

- As long as the array is `static`, the above optimization will happen no matter if we use `const` or not.
- If we remove `static` but keep `const`, then other parts of the program might access the array but not change it, so the same optimization is still possible.
- If we remove both of `static` and `const`, then the compiler can no longer assume that this array isn't modified from elsewhere. And therefore the compiler is forced to allocate it as an array in the data section and read it from that memory location during printing.

---

> Specifically, is a static const array 'simply' the executable's data that is loaded in memory vs a copy of that array in case of only static ?

Assuming that the array is actually allocated in the data section and not optimized into machine code, then:

- On a "hosted system" (for example Linux x86) then constant data from the executable file is loaded into the array's memory location at the point when the executable is loaded into RAM.
- On a "freestanding system" (for example a microcontroller with flash memory) then:

  - In case of `static` + `const`, the array is stored in true read-only flash memory with no copies of it anywhere.
  - In case of `static` and/or declaration at file scope but no `const`, the array is stored in RAM and the initializer values for it will have to be allocated in read-only flash. During program start-up, the flash data is copied into the array in RAM.

At some extent, the "C runtime" (CRT) of various hosted system compilers might do something similar as the above freestanding scenario - keep a copy of initializer values which are uploaded into the array during start-up. In case of C++ classes for example, there may be default constructors which perform something more intricate than just copying values.

---

> Is there any difference with declaring inside a function instead, in terms of memory ?

This is another story entirely. Local scope variables that are `static` work the same as any other `static` variable in terms of allocation/initialization. But plain local scope variables "with automatic storage" are stored in registers or on the stack, and they are set up anew each time the scope where they were declared is entered. So these will require the default initialization values to be copied from read-only memory elsewhere.

And here it won't matter if the local variable is `const` or not, it will still get allocated in a register/on the stack and initialized from read-only memory.